# VS & Anaconda Launcher

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda

I am pretty much brand new to python. I have been learning from an udemy course and started with some small projects for fun.

I recently setup anaconda and use their launcher to load the env I want to use. I set this up so I could help have better control over my environments.

Every time I ran VS after setting the env in the anaconda application It would automatically type something and load into that env. For some reason this has stopped happening and I am not sure how to manually call it even. I was reading on their website about some conda commands but nothing seems to work for me. Im sure I am doing something very simple wrong here.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: first some stupid questions,sorry!  Did you remember to activate your virtual environment every time?  Did you try 'conda update conda' and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes i run the anaconda program and the select my virtual environment and it loads. I can then launch python or terminal from the anaconda software and it works. I just cant seem to get it to work in vs. In the VS terminal I always just get 'conda is not recognized'